# rename all files in folder with random name

Tags: php

I want to rename all files in a folder with random numbers or characters.

This my code:

```
$dir = opendir('2009111');
$i = 1;
// loop through all the files in the directory
while ( false !== ( $file = readdir($dir) ) ) {
        // do the rename based on the current iteration
        $newName = rand()  . (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        rename($file, $newName);
        // increase for the next loop
        $i++;
}
// close the directory handle
closedir($dir);
```

but I get this error:

> Warning: rename(4 (2).jpg,8243.jpg): The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve by doing this? And what is the error you're getting?

Comment: 1. *but this error*, what error? 2. There's no point using variable `$i` in your `while()` loop.

Comment: Warning: rename(4 (2).jpg,8243.jpg): The system cannot find the file specified  ...

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through files in the directory `2009111/`, but then you refer to them without the directory prefix in `rename()`.

Something like this should work better (*though see the warning about **data loss** below*):

```
$oldName = '2009111/' . $file;
$newName = '2009111/' . rand()  . (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

rename($oldName, $newName);
```

Of course, you may want to put the directory name in a variable or make other similar tweaks. I'm still not clear on why you're trying to do this, and depending on your goals there may be better ways of reaching them.

***Warning!** The approach you are using could cause data loss!* A `$newName` could be generated that is the same name as an existing file, and [`rename()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) overwrites target files.

You should probably make sure `$newName` doesn't [exist](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) before you `rename()`.